# Arithmetic and geometric genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

There are two notion of genus in algebraic geometry, namely arithmetic genus $p_a=(-1)^{\dim X}(\chi(\mathcal{O}_X)-1)$ and geometric genus $p_g=\dim H^0(X,\Omega^{\dim X})$. I keep forgetting definition of these, or being confused which is which. Are there any good ways to remember them?

More precisely I would like to associate these definition with these names "arithmetic" and "geometric".

Comment: You might  look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163407/3217)

Comment: As a sort of mnemonic, I tell myself that *geometric genus* counts something geometric, like holes or independant loops or independant cycles and is thus always positive or zero, whereas *arithmetic genus* has some pleasant formal properties (which is why  Hirzebruch  introduced them) but has no geometric interpretation  and in particular may  even be negative.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your curves becomes singular (say, nodal), then the arithmetic genus stays the same, while geometric genus drops.

From another point of view, your curve is arithmetically the same, (say, still a degree d plane curve), while geometrically (and topologically!) is different.

I believe that this is not only a natural way to remember, but, possibly, also how these terms appeared historically. (Severi studying nodal curves)